# IE 8 acts different on different machines

Tags: jquery, css, html, internet-explorer-8

What can be the reason for IE 8 acting different on two different machines?

On this site:
http://www.activ-gmbh.de

When you maximize one of the slideshows and then try to minimize it again, the "X" just disappears and nothing happens on one machine. On the other machine it works even in IE6.

Comment: Check if Compatibility Mode is on or not.

Comment: Have you checked that the browser is not running in Quirks mode or Compatibility mode? You can check by clicking Tools -> Compatibility Mode and seeing if it is checked.

Comment: i know you can't see me right now but i'm making my best 'not surprised' face. but on the bright side, atleast I don't have to support complicated javascript / jQuery apps on IE 5.5 anymore. OT: I'd also throw in with checking quirks mode - you can also install the IE8 dev tools which are surprisingly good for something spewed forth from redmond. Press f12 to access them. sorry for the wrong link, forgot they are included now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, 'cause the IE8-to-IE7 compatibility mode was auto-enabled on Intranet websites (Oo?!), so my IE8 thought he was a IE7. If that's also your problem, add

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```

in the `head` of your HTML document. That will force IE8 reacting like IE8... Thanks MS!

Comment: Thank you very much. That really was the problem. However, I found another solution using the .htaccess file included in html5 boilerplate. Look [here](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/378)

Comment: Yeah, seems to be a good solution too! However, using the `<meta>` trick, no matter what the server you use. But thanks anyway :) Do you use jQuery in your app? 'Cause detecting the browser using JS was a different story when that compatibility mode was enabled.

Comment: Yes I am using jQuery but I didn’t need to detect the browser.